# kali and Tripura sundari as both adya shakti in different times?

Tags: kali

are there any sri vidya gurus that consider both kali and tripura sundari as adya shakti?why do enlightened masters of different lineages consider one above the other?if they are both enlightened and omniscient shouldn't they agree?

> Kaulas have been criticised as their works emphasise love and death, but they were always realists. Many tantras establish that the terrifying Kali and the benign Lalita are two sides of the same coin. This coin or currency is called life. Lalita, with her waxing moon, represents creation, and Kalika with her waning moon dissolution. Each is a complete symbol, of high sublimity and loaded with spiritual significance.

do you know wich tantras say that they are two sides of the same coin?

Comment: Could you share the source of quoted part?